# Having trouble with my accordion Form

Tags: jquery, html

So I've been trying to build this responsive form which slides up when in mobile form into a accordion, but once it hits tablet or Desktop size the accordion is removed and so become a normal again.

I am able to make it hide in mobile size, but how I do I remove the icons and slide up/ slide down function in the desktop.

[My Accordion Responsive Form](http://codepen.io/Markj89/pen/kCsgI)

Comment: For future reference please post code _on_ the site. Not on another site. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A quick media query should do the trick! If they can't see the buttons they can't click them right?

```
.fa-plus, .fa-minus {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 7px;
    display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .fa-plus, .fa-minus {
         display: block;
    }
}
```

As far as JavaScript is concerned, you could check the width of the page and only show/hide your toggle if it's "mobile mode"